# How to trun off laravel debug mode

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, content-management-system

I get this Error in the Log file. The Problem is in the CMS i try to deaktivated the debu-mod. But i dont will turn off.

in the Logs i get this Error-Message and i think thats the reasson why it dont will turn off.

> production.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'option_id' cannot be null in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:449

Tank your for your help :)

Comment: Hey, try to change APP_DEBUG=true in the .env file to APP_DEBUG=false to turn off the debugging messages.

Comment: You should fix the error first

Answer (score 3):

Set `APP_DEBUG=true` to `APP_DEBUG=false` in `.env` file to turn off debugging messages in production mode.

Answer (score 2):

goto 
Laravel Project 
    config/app.php

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),
```

or 
   .ENV

```
APP_DEBUG=false
```

Answer (score 1):

The amount of error detail your application displays through the browser is controlled by the app.debug configuration option in your config/app.php configuration file. By default, this configuration option is set to respect the APP_DEBUG environment variable, which is stored in your .env file.

1) **Local development**, you should set the **APP_DEBUG** environment variable to **true**.

2) **Production environment**, this value should always be **false**.

**.env file**

```
APP_DEBUG=false // when you are in the production environment

APP_DEBUG=true // when you are in local development
```

[laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/errors#configuration)